# Why NLog does not archive every day

Tags: nlog

NLog archive every day not working. But it works for every Minute
NLog version 5.0.7

This is my configuration

```
<target name="Httpfile"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} correlationId-${activityid} - ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
            xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${logFullName}-http-api-${shortdate}.log"
            archiveFileName="${logFullNameArchive}-archive-Http-api-${shortdate}-{#####}.zip"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            keepFileOpen="false" 
            archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
            maxArchiveFiles="30"
            maxArchiveDays="7"
            enableArchiveFileCompression="true"  
            />
```

with archiveEvery="Minute" it works very well

Answer (score 0):

It is not [supported to mix](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic) static- and dynamic-archive-logic in [NLog FileTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target).

When using static-archive-logic, then you should not use `${shortdate}` inside `fileName="..."` and `archiveFileName="..."`.

Some features like `enableArchiveFileCompression="true"` are only supported by static-archive-logic:

```xml
<target name="Httpfile"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} correlationId-${activityid} - ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
            xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${logFullName}-http-api.log"
            archiveFileName="${logFullNameArchive}-archive-Http-api-{#####}.zip"
            archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            keepFileOpen="false" 
            maxArchiveFiles="30"
            maxArchiveDays="7"
            enableArchiveFileCompression="true"  
            />
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples